# MySQLi + PHP | Выводить результат с последней строки по порядку

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

У меня есть такой код

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `popolnenie` WHERE poplnenie_login='{$userdata['user_login']}'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
    foreach($result as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style=\"width:40px;\">" . $row["poplnenie_id"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style=\"width:350px;\">" . $row["poplnenie_address"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style=\"width:130px;\">" . $row["poplnenie_btc"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style=\"width:70px;\">" . $row["poplnenie_usd"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style=\"width:105px;\">" . $row["poplnenie_data"] . "</td>";
        if($row["poplnenie_gotovo"] == 0) {echo "<td>" . "<form method=\"POST\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"paltezh\" value=" . $row["poplnenie_id"] . " /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Я оплатил\"></form>" . "</td>";};
        if($row["poplnenie_gotovo"] == 1) {echo "<td>" . "Платеж зачислен" . "</td>";};
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Он выводит такую таблицу:
[image: Таблица]

Подскажите как перебрать таблицу с последнего элемента, чтобы перебор и печать шла не по порядку

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

А наоборот, в обратном порядке

```
ID
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: `ORDER BY poplnenie_id DESC`

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось:
"SELECT * FROM `popolnenie` WHERE poplnenie_login='{$userdata['user_login']}' ORDER BY poplnenie_id DESC";